# Is there a way to perform an action based on attaching a knowledge article to case in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, knowledge

We are migrating to LEX and moving from solution to articles (rather reluctantly). in our current solution we customised the solution object to add case type, subtype and status fields. When an agent attaches the soltuion then we basically copy the values from the solution onto the case and close it.

In the new world, what I have now found out is that the case article object doesnt support triggers, ok I thought a feed item is created when you attach an article so I can do that, unfortunately the feed item trigger only works on certain types of feed item.

I am trying to find a solution to catch the event of attaching an article to a case can be either in Apex or config I dont care but as of yet I dont see a way to do this without completely building a new Lightning component.

If anyone has managed this I would love to know how

Comment: Check the responses on the question [How to update a field in a case when an article is attached?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278155/how-to-update-a-field-in-a-case-when-an-article-is-attached), does this help ?

Comment: thanks for that but not really that issue also doesnt appear to be solved and I am pretty sure they will hit the same issue as I have

Comment: Mentioned in the comment, the best solution for now might be to have a scheduled job to search for those feed posts that don't get caught in the trigger. It's not immediate, but it'd at least eventually get info onto the case.