# FeedItem Trigger is not executing

Tags: trigger, case, knowledge, feeditem, articles

I have a trigger in FeedItem which needs to fire when an article is attached to the case. Here is the trigger:

```
trigger FeedItemTrg on FeedItem (after insert, after update) {
    for (FeedItem fi : trigger.new)  {
        if (fi.Type == 'AttachArticleEvent') {
            System.debug('**** Trigger Value *** '+fi); 
        }
    }
}
```

When I attach the article I don't see this trigger getting executed. But when i run a SOQL query on FeedItem object I am able to see the record.

[image]

Can anyone guide me on how to fix this issue? My requirement is when an Article is attached to a case. I need to get some information from the attached article and populate it in the case record.

Comment: are you talking about knowledge article?

Comment: yes, @sanketkumar. When a knowledge article is added to a case I need to copy a few values from that article to the case.

Comment: Based on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278155/how-to-update-a-field-in-a-case-when-an-article-is-attached looks like the trigger is not firing if the type of the feedItem record is 'AttachArticleEvent'.  Does the approach of using scheduled job as mentioned by cropredy work for you? Thanks

Comment: Hi, @Swetha thanks for your comment. My requirement is it should happen in realtime. yes, I suggest batch job but the client told me the current legacy system is doing this we want the same in SF also.